# ValueProperty Change Listener

Tags: java, events, javafx, slider

I have this following problem:

I have a customized Dual-Slider, it is very important to check every Value Change of this slider!
[image]

If i change now the left or the right Slider there is a Event - Handling! If i make a click on the Line of the Slider there is also a Event, but its incorrect!

When i click on the Line of the Slider, booth Sliders will jump together, the Values are actual, but there is only 1 Event-Handelt!

How can i bind this Events together?

```
 m_slider.value1Property().addListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
            {
                try
                {
                    handleSlider();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        });

        m_slider.value2Property().addListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
            {
                try
                {
                    handleSlider();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }

        });
```

Here you can see my Event-Binding! If the Value1 (Left Slider) or Value2 (Right Slider) change there values, there is a Event-Trigger. But if booth of them changes there Values (click on the line of the sliders) there is only 1 Event-Trigger and not booth!

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Would probably be useful to see what your customer slider is doing.

Comment: How can I give you this Information? What do you need?

Comment: I haven't used JavaFX before, but if I wanted to verify this sort of behavior myself I couldn't because I don't have enough information. In other words, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed if I wanted to explore how to solve this.

Comment: Ok!I will add some more informations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I have to add the Change-Listener Event to the textProperty!
If there is a changing, the Event will handel anything else!

```
        m_minSlider.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
            {
                handleSlider();
            }
        });

        m_maxSlider.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
            {
                handleSlider();
            }
        });
```